# Can marginals determine all probabilities

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, marginal-distribution, marginal-probability

suppose we are given $n$ binary random variables, $X_1,\dots,X_n$.
A probability distribution $P$ assigns all elementary events a probability;
$$ P(X_1=x_1\&\ldots \& X_n=x_n)\in[0,1].$$

A regular marginal $m_I$ is a probability function on a proper(!) subset of variables: Given a proper subset $I\subset \{1,\dots,n\}$, a regular marginal $m_I$ assigns all events described by this set of variables a non-zero probability:
$$m_I(X_{i_1}=x_{i_1}\&\dots\&X_{i_{|I|}}=x_{i_{|I|}})>0.$$

Does a given set of regular marginals determine a probability distribution $P$?
In other words, are there cases in which there exists only a single distribution $P$ that agrees with all given marginals?

Obviously, the given marginals must agree on joint domains; i.e., they must be consistent.

The regularity condition of the marginals matters here: If $n=2$, $m_1(X_1=x_1)=1$ and $m_2(X_2=x_2)=1$, then there exists a unique $P$ that agrees with these two marginals; $P$ is simply given by $P(X_1=x_1 \& X_2=x_2)=1$.

I think that there are cases for all $n\geq 2$ in which no set of regular marginals determines a unique probability distribution $P$. I would like to be sure! Also, I would like to have a reference.

All help is much appreciated,

Juergen

Here's an example:
$X_1$ concerns the outcomes of a coin toss.
$X_2$ concerns whether my favourite team wins or looses.
$X_3$ concerns whether it rains tomorrow or not.
...

A marginal $m_I$ provides probabilistic information about a subset of these events.

For all fixed $n\geq 3$ (jakobdt solved the case for $n=2$), does there exist a case in which we have specified marginals for all $I$ with $|I|=n-1$ such that there are multiple probability distributions agreeing with all marginals?

Comment: Try $n=2$ where the marginal probabilities are neither $1$ nor $0$

Comment: Yes, for $n=2$ the marginals do not determine the distribution $P$.

How about the same question for general $n$?
I still think that the marginals do not determine a unique $P$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X_1$ be Bernoulli distributed with parameter $p=1/2$. Here are two choices of $X_2$ for which the marginal distribution $m_2$ is the same but the joint distribution of $(X_1,X_2)$ is not:

1. $X_2=X_1$.
2. $X_2=1-X_1$.

Comment: Thanks for this jakobdt. Unfortunately, I don't quite get this.

My question rather is (a more general version of the following):

Suppose $X_1$ is Bernoulli distributed with parameter $p_1\in (0,1)$.
Suppose $X_2$ is Bernoulli distributed with parameter $p_2\in (0,1)$.

Does there exist a unique probability distribution $P$ on $(X_1,X_2)$ that agrees with these two Bernoulli distribution?
Note that I do not make any assumptions on $P$. So, it does not matter whether $P$ is Bernoulli distributed or not.

Comment: If you let $U$ uniformly distributed in $(0,1)$ then you can construct $X_1$ and $X_2$ by taking $X_i=f_i(U)$, where $f_i\colon(0,1)\to\{0,1\}$ is such that the set $\{u\in(0,1)\mid f_i(u)=1\}$ has Lebesgue measure $p_i$. Some examples are $f_i=1_{(0,p_i)}$, $f_i=1_{(1-p_i,1)}$ and $f_i=1_{(0,p_i/2)}+1_{(1-p_i/2,1)}$. The point is that $P$ depends on the choice of these functions. For simplicity, just look at how $P(X=Y)$ can vary accordingly. In my example above this probability is either $1$ or $0$.

Comment: I'm beginning to see. If $n=2$, then two marginals (both defined over a single variable) do not determine $P$. Good.

I'm mostly interested in the case for general $n$.
Are there cases in which a number of marginals (defined over at most $n-1$ variables) determine $P$?

Comment: Let $(X_1,...,X_n)$ be uniformly distributed over the $2^{n-1}$ binary words with an even number of $1$s in them.  Then all $n-1$ dimensional marginals are uniform, that is, are the same as those of $(Y_1,...,Y_n)$ where the $Y_i$ are independent uniform 0-1 variables.